# Regex wrap first integer in span with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a cms that is returning a list like so:

> 1 This is the first list item 100 people have seen it
>
> 2 This is the second list item 29 people have seen it

I need to wrap the first integer in a span to style the list items (altering the output rendered is not an option), to achieve the following:

```
<span>2</span> This is the second list item 29 people have seen it
```

I currently have:

```
return v.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
```

But that is replacing all integers. I have tried the following with no luck:

```
return v.replace(/(\^d+)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
```

What is the best way I can achieve this?

Comment: Thank you! Also I just realized I was replacing across the ul instead of the li. Woops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`g` means `global`, you only need replace the first match then you don't need to use `g` modifier.

```
return v.replace(/(\d+)/, '<span>$1</span>');
```

And your second piece of code put `\` in wrong place.

```
return v.replace(/^(\d+)/, '<span>$1</span>');
```

Comment: Regex quick on the draw. Nice.